# conan installed but no command found

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, conan

Installation is successful but where is conan?

1. Installed using "sudo pip install conan" (success)
2. source ~/.profile
3. conan (No command 'conan' found)

I looked with "pip show conan" and it returns location is /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

Comment: I am on a Ubuntu 16.04 (in a VM in a Windows Laptop). Conan is a C++ package manager.  It is a python program. As  I indicated, I do see conan related files appear to have been installed in dist-packges. I wonder if some links weren't established.

Comment: You installed using pip which is follow a specific python version (probably you have more than one python version installed). The most safe form for installing a package is running `python -m pip install conan`. Where python can python2, python3. So you can run with `python3` and take a look in the result

Comment: I was able to install it as a debian package. I wasn't able to get a pip based installation to work.

Comment: Thanks @uilianries. I do have mulitple versions of python. I will try your suggestion. (I am guessing that you are right).

Answer (score 2):

It seems after you installed conan with pip / pip3 it is not in the environment variable PATH. You need to find where conan was installed and add path to conan to PATH.

```
find /usr/local -name conan
```

and if conan was installed to /usr/local/bin
add it to PATH

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

It is possible that you want to update your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc to add path to conan to PATH.